# How to search for data in large array

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am looking for suggestion on how to search or lookup the data relating to specific line of data. Running Microsoft Excel 365 and SQL Server 2014. In my case I have job lines stored in a SQL table. A second table has a number of manufacturing operations, numbering from 1 to many that relate to each line.

**Job Detail List**

| Job # | Assembly # | Assembly Part # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0 | A1 |
| 1002 | 0 | B1 |
| 1002 | 1 | B10 |
| 1002 | 2 | B11 |
| 1003 | 0 | C1 |
| 1003 | 1 | C10 |

**Job Operation List**

| Job # | Assembly # | OpSeq | OpCode | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0 | 10 | MF | 1.2 |
| 1001 | 0 | 20 | FA | 2.0 |
| 1001 | 0 | 30 | Paint | 0.5 |
| 1002 | 0 | 10 | MF | 2.5 |
| 1002 | 1 | 10 | MF | 1.5 |
| 1002 | 1 | 20 | Prep | 1.0 |
| 1002 | 1 | 30 | Paint | 1.5 |
| 1002 | 2 | 10 | FA | 0.5 |
| 1002 | 2 | 20 | Pack | 0.5 |

The Job Detail lines as stored in the following

```
Public Type JobStatusDetailLine
    JobNum As String
    AssemblySeq As Integer
    PartNum As String
    ...
End Type

Public JobStatusDetailArr() As JobStatusDetailLine
```

Job Operation List

```
Public Type JobStatusOperations
    JobNum As String
    AssemblySeq As Integer
    OpSeq As Integer
    OpCode As String
    Hours As Double
    ...
End Type

Public JobStatusOperationArr() As JobStatusOperations
```

**Excel Table Output**

| Job # | Operation # | Op1 | Op2 | Op3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0 | MF | FA | Paint |
| 1002 | 0 | MF | - | - |
| 1002 | 1 | MF | Prep | Paint |
| 1002 | 2 | FA | Pack | - |

Currently, I read all job lines into JobStatusDetailArr, then iterate through the array adding a new line to an Excel table. On each iteration I lookup the operation for that job and read them into JobStatusOperationArr. I then iterate through the array and append each operation as a column of the line in the table. Depending on the number of job lines and number of operations per job (some jobs can have 20 - 30 operations), it can be slow to generate the table.

An alternative may to to read all operations for every job into a large array. But I don't know of an efficient way to find the operations related to the current job line as I iterate through the JobStatusDetailArr to build each table line.

What is a better approach to looking up the operations for each job line?

Also, there is conditional formatting on the table operation cell based on the operation hours and if the operation is complete (not shown in my operation table)

Comment: Why in the world do you need an array here? It is not clear. Why wouldn't you do a single query? (I can't supply code, because from your story it is not really clear what you are trying to do) Can you provide sample result Excel for example (likely a simple QueryTables.Add or CopyFromRecordset would do the job).

Comment: Added more detail of the Excel Output

Comment: I have edited your question and submitted it to be re-opened. I can't guarantee it will be reopened so avoid wording questions so they sound as if you are soliciting an opinon to avoid this in future. If it is reopened then I have a SQL solution for you

Comment: Looking at your expected output, simply use a Pivot table. Excel is good at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move away from thinking in rows, especially as your data is on a SQL database. SQL is set-based - no need to use loops. The data can be extracted from the SQL tables with each row already constructed with the data you require

I mimicked what might be your SQL tables with the following sample data

```
declare @JobDetail table(jobno varchar(5), assemblyno int, partno varchar(5));
insert into @JobDetail(jobno, assemblyno, partno) values
 ('1001',0,'A1')
,('1002',0,'B1')
,('1002',1,'B10')
,('1002',2,'B11')
,('1003',0,'C1')
,('1003',1,'C10');

declare @JobOperation table (jobno varchar(5), assemblyno int, opseq int, opcode varchar(5), [hours] decimal(15,2));
insert into @JobOperation(jobno, assemblyno, opseq, opcode, [hours]) values
 ('1001',0,10,'MF',1.2)
,('1001',0,20,'FA',2.0)
,('1001',0,30,'Paint',0.5)
,('1002',0,10,'MF',2.5)
,('1002',1,10,'MF',1.5)
,('1002',1,20,'Prep ',1.0)
,('1002',1,30,'Paint',1.5)
,('1002',2,10,'FA',0.5)
,('1002',2,20,'Pack ',0.5);
```

Then the data extraction could look something like this

```
select jobno, assemblyno
    ,MAX(ISNULL([10],'-')) AS OP1
    ,MAX(ISNULL([20],'-')) AS OP2
    ,MAX(ISNULL([30],'-')) AS OP3
    ,SUM(ISNULL([hours],0)) as tothours
from
(
    select a.jobno, a.assemblyno, b.opseq, b.opcode, b.hours
    from @JobDetail a
    left join @JobOperation b on a.jobno = b.jobno and a.assemblyno = b.assemblyno
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(OPCODE) for opseq in ([10],[20],[30])
) pvt
where [10] is not null or [20] is not null or [30] is not null
group by jobno, assemblyno
ORDER BY jobno, assemblyno;
```

Results

```
jobno   assemblyno  OP1 OP2     OP3     tothours
1001    0           MF  FA      Paint   3.70
1002    0           MF  -       -       2.50
1002    1           MF  Prep    Paint   2.50
1002    2           FA  Pack    -       0.50
```

If you prefer to have the data separately in your workbook, then as @cetin basoz suggests, just use a Pivot Table